# Limit user to only allow generation of SAS tokens for a storage account

Tags: azure

I want to allow our helpdesk to generate SAS tokens for one storage account. (It is where SQL backups get stored and helpdesk on occasion need to extract them)
I don't want the helpdesk to be able to create or delete containers etc.. or make changes to the storage account.

I have created what I think looks like a reasonable role template for this, however my test account can still add containers, upload files and make some changes to the storage account configuration.

What am I missing?

```
{
"properties": {
    "roleName": "Helpdesk Generate SAS Key Access",
    "description": "Gives limited access to the storage account can generate SA level SAS tokens",
    "assignableScopes": [
        "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx"
    ],
    "permissions": [
        {
            "actions": [
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/generateUserDelegationKey/action",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listkeys/action"
            ],
            "notActions": [
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/write",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/read",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/write",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/delete",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/read",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/lease/action",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/clearLegalHold/action",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/setLegalHold/action",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/write",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues/delete",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues/read",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues/write",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices/read",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices/write",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices/tables/delete",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices/tables/write",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices/tables/read"
            ],
            "dataActions": [],
            "notDataActions": [
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/fileshares/files/delete",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/fileshares/files/write",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/fileshares/files/modifypermissions/action",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/fileshares/files/actassuperuser/action",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/read",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/write",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/delete",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/deleteBlobVersion/action",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/add/action",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/filter/action",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/move/action",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/manageOwnership/action",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/runAsSuperUser/action",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/modifyPermissions/action",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues/messages/read",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues/messages/write",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues/messages/delete",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues/messages/add/action",
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues/messages/process/action"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}